# How to stop click the same button while the button always exist by selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I faced one issue, before when I scrape multiple pages by Selenium, just use click next page button and use `NoSuchElementException` to stop it.

But the url I facing now is  the element always exists, in the last page, if I  click next page button, it just reload the current page.

Anyone Can help to  solve how to stop click the same button?

```
items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
while True:
        try:
            #click next page
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('下一页').click()
            sleep(5)
            #scrpae data here
            items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')

            for i in range(0, len(items)):

               results.append(items[i])
               print(items[i])
             
              
              
        except NoSuchElementException:
            
            break
```

For the pages details you can check the picture below

[image]
[Fullsize image](https://snag.gy/rGpoh5.jpg)

Comment: resource page link?

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]

You can solve it by matching current page url and next page url in next page link.
if current page url matches the url in next page link then it is the last page. otherwise continue **scraping**.

You should have a variable where you store current page URL and when you click on next page link by selenium, you get the page url and match with previous.

This is what i am saying:

```
url = "https://humkinar.com.pk/"
driver.get(url)
items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
current_page_url = ""
prev_page_url = url
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('下一页').click()
        current_page_url = driver.current_url
        if current_page_url != prev_page_url:
            time.sleep(5)
            items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
            for i in range(0, len(items)):
               results.append(items[i])
               print(items[i])
            prev_page_url = current_page_url
        else:
            break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: would you mind show me any code for our reference? thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get current url from selenium web driver like this
`print driver.current_url`

Comment: if you want complete code i can send you by editing your code.

Answer (score 1):

As i see in picture (i suppose picture you shared is of last page),check for `className == 'disable'` in `<a class='disable'> <some text in chinese></a>` and `break;`

UPDATE:

```
items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
while True:
    try:
        #click next page
        next = driver.find_element_by_link_text('下一页')
        next.click()
        sleep(5)
        #scrpae data here
        items=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')

        for i in range(0, len(items)):

           results.append(items[i])
           print(items[i])

           break;        
       if(next.getAttribute('class') == 'disable'){
          throw new Exception()
       }
```

Comment: Hi, Mr. Yogendra Porwal, Thank you very much for your answer, would you mind tell me why I get error as below: File "<ipython-input-10-ab3da9243700>", line 18
    if(next.getAttribute('class') == 'disable'){
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    ====>you can try run this url [link](https://jxmk.taobao.com/category-1088127400.htm)

Comment: this a java syntax please use an `if` syntax valid for python :)